# On smoothness and roughness of a number related to triangular numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences, smoothness

Define $\triangle_n$ to be the $n$th triangular number.

Define $$M_n=(2\triangle_n-1)2\triangle_n(2\triangle_n+1)=2\triangle_n(4\triangle_n^2-1).$$

Define $(\ell,k)$-smough numbers to be numbers that have all prime divisors $p$ of the form of either $p<\ell$ or $k<p$.

1. Is there an $\ell_0\geq6$ such that for every $\ell>\ell_0$ there is a $k_\ell$ such that for every $k\geq k_\ell$ there is always an $n$ such that $M_n$ is $(\ell,k)$-smough?
2. Given an $\ell$ and a $k$, how small can $n$ be such that $M_n$ is $(\ell,k)$-smough?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the $\triangle$ and $\square$ notation standard?

Comment: $\triangle$ is standard for triangular numbers. $\square$ represents sum of cubes (three dimensional squares).

Comment: Right right sorry I read in the post, was just wondering if that notation is commonly used

Comment: $\triangle$ was used by Gauss.